Why doesn't SSAS connect to SQL Server?
I've been trying to create a cube in SSAS but it just doesn't want to connect to SQL Server although the server name I enter is the same? What could be the problem?


I tried to ignore it and went with the 'Integrated workspace' option and it didn't deploy. I changed the server from localhost to my SQL Server name in the solution explorer properties but still doesn't work.

Is the SSAS service actually running?

SSMS is connected to SQL Server Database Engine, not Analysis Services.  Should look like this:

Ensure you've got Analysis Services installed and the service is running.
PS C:\Users\david> Get-Service  *olap*

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  MSSQLServerOLAP... SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQL...

